# Finding maximal linearly independent subset

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following matrix composed of 4 column vectors. I need to find the maximal linearly independent subset.

[image]

After row reducing, I get the following matrix:

[image]

It's my understanding that the columns with pivots would represent the linearly independent vectors. So we would have columns 1 and 2 from the original matrix as the linearly independent vectors. But if we look carefully at the original matrix, we realize that column 2 can be represented as the sum of column 1 and 3, which would make column 2 to be linearly dependent.

What am I getting wrong? The solution to this exercise points that vectors 1, 3 and 4 form the maximal linearly independent subset.

Comment: In your second matrix the pivots are in the first, second and fourth columns.

Comment: Is there a pivot on the fourth column? I thought the pivot on the fourth column would have to be placed on a_4,4 position.

Comment: I see a pivot in column $4$, standing out proud!

Answer (score 1):

In squared matrices, the dimension of the columns vector space equals the dimension of the rows vector space.

Since you performed row reduction, you can find the maximal subset of the **rows** space.

In order to find the subset for the columns space (which is different from the rows space, but equals in their dimensions) - you will have to perform row reduction over the matrix $A^t$.

notice that the rank of the matrix you have is $3$, and for any squared matrix $A: \ rank(A) = dim(R(A)) = dim(C(A))$, and $R(A)$ will be the rows space and $C(A)$ will be the columns space.

***EDIT***

let  $A = \{ (1,0,1,0), (1,1,1,1), (0,1,0,1), (2,0,-1,0)\}$.

I'd like to presnt this vectors in a matrix form, meaning $(x,y,z,w) \in A$
therefore:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
2 & 0 & -1 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$

I will let you preform the calculations, but you should be getting: $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$

Notice that the origina location of each vector in a given row has might changed.

Comment: I'm confused. The exercise goes as follows: Find a maximal linearly independent subset of each of the following sets of vectors in Rˆ4.

A = { (1,0,1,0), (1,1,1,1), (0,1,0,1), (2,0,-1,0)}.

So I wrote the vectors as columns. After row reducing, would not it give me the column space based on the pivots?

Comment: @MiltonLeal if you wrote them as columns, by preforming row reduction you will change the vector space you we're given. try to write them as rows of a matrix (as each column respresents a variable, and not a vector), and then to preform row reduction. this will might solve your problem

Comment: So based on the RREF matrix you just posted, how do I identify which of the vectors is linearly dependent? The fact that the second row has an element 1 on the fourth column means that the original second row representing that vector is the linearly dependent vector?

Comment: Let $v_1 =(1,0,1,0),v_2 =(1,1,1,1), v_3=(0,1,0,1),v_4= (2,0,-1,0)\}$. 
let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ and look for which scalars $v_2 = av_1 +bv_3 + dv_4$